# MVC Custom validation: DataAnnotations or IValidatableObject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I've a question about the different ways of creating a custom validation on MVC.
I've to combine two pieces of code that are doing the same thing in two different Areas (MVC Area) of the website. This piece of code is validating a bank account number. One of the versions is using custom validation attribute and the other one IValidatableObject.
Now I've to merge everything in one place and add some extra functionality.

Is there any advantage of using one implementation over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IValidatableObject is used when you need validation logic which is not available with existing attributes. So I think it's okay to use attributes if they fit your validation rules. If your validation rules are complex, you can use IValidatableObject interface to implement your own logic.

Comment: Hi Roman,
You can also achieve that by creating your own custom validation attributes. Plus, with the custom validation attributes you can also add client-side validation.
Is there any other difference?